# Deployment of Apps at AWS opsworks. Why deployment randmomly fails?

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-opsworks

I have an AWS Opsworks Stack, and it has a Rails layer with many instances.

When I deploy an app in general it works. But sometimes the app returns a server error in some instances (500 error). It is fixed by redeploying to the problematic instance.

Is there a way to prevent this issues? Why the same app works in some instances and not others? And why redeploying fixes the issue?

Thanks in advance

**SOLUTION**

- Reducing nginx worker connections
- Or get an instance type with more memory.
- Rarely github checkout fails. If this happens you just need to restart the instance and it usually solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the deployment log will tell you what went wrong.

This does happen sometimes, and it is usually due to the SCM. In our case, randomly we'll get an error about github, and nothing would be checkout.

Comment: Thanks. In my case the error went away by having more memory in the instance, or reducing nginx worker connections.